# Ports in herokuapp

Tags: javascript, heroku, webrtc, peerjs

So, I recently deployed a PeerJS app to heroku. I created an instance of a PeerJSserver like this: (as mentioned on their github page)

```
// determining the port
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || '3000');

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);
});

// peerjs server setup
var peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server);
app.use('/app', peerServer);
peerServer.on('connection', function(id) { console.log(id); });
```

and on the client side, I wanna connect to this server, like this:

```
<script>
    var peer = new Peer('someid', {host: '/', port: 9000, path: '/app'});
</script>
```

**The Problem:**
So, you already know that heroku randomly decides a port on which the app should be running. If I check my logs, I can see the port on which the server is running. So, how can I determine the port on the client side? I've tried not giving the object constructor a port and it automatically gives it a port of **9000** (which i think is the default).

So, should I query the server to determine its port? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: just remove the port and use url of your webpage.

Comment: @IshankGulati its gives me a "not resolved" error and in the error, it can be seen that it tries to connect to "mysite.heroku.com:9000" so it automatically tries to connect to the 9000 port, if i don't give it

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was:

```
var peer = new Peer({host: '/', port: '', path: '/app'});
```

Hope it helps :)